How to find MSVC compiler intrinsics (builtin functions) depending on the compiler version
I have a hard time finding a website or any document which shows which builtin functions or features are available for a specific MSVC version.
I am personally not using MSVC but my program should be able to be compiled using MSVC. For example GNU C compilers implement __builtin_unreachable() function and MSVC to my knowledge also implements __assume().
Now how would I know which version of MSVC has this builtin function so that I can use macro directives to enable it? Additionally same for GCC I have hard time finding which version supports which builtin functions or features, but at least it was quite easy to find GCC changelogs (which are not ideal many things are not documented or are missing).

Some of the intrinsics have been there since the 1980s, so perhaps nobody knows. In this specific case, Herb Sutter "Assumptions" (section 2.1.1) claims that __assume was added in 1998. So seems safe to use.

If you just want to verify that certain compilers support some built-ins, you can use the "conformance viewer" feature of compiler explorer: https://godbolt.org/z/jjKzKMY1z -- this shows that gcc supports __builtin_unreachable() from (at least) version 4.5.3, clang from at least 3.0.0, and MSVC currently not at all (there aren't many much older MSVC versions though). Otherwise, asking for guides/online resources is generally off-topic on SO.

@BoP thanks for info, shame that these compiler features are not well documented.
